# For %%B really acting up

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I hope that a clever head can help me here, because I am surly puzzled.

This is part of a larger script, but this is the one really puzzling me.

```
    for %%B in (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14) do (

set tjek2=

echo %%B
if %%B LSS 4 set isnow=_POS0%%B DT_pos-db.xml
if %%B GTR 3 set isnow=_POS0%%B FC_pos-db.xml
if %%B GTR 7 set isnow=_POS0%%B FC_pos-db.xml
if %%B GTR 9 set isnow=_POS0%%B FC_pos-db.xml
echo !isnow!
pause
)
```

Everything actually works great, until I reach Nr 8 and Nr 9.
The code then outputs:

```
_POS008 DT_pos-db.xml
_POS009 DT_pos-db.xml
```

And for the life if me I cannot fathom why it is not writing it as a FC_pos-db, as the previous 4 listed.

Anyone who can help explain this for me?

Note, the

```
if %%B GTR 7 set isnow=_POS0%%B FC_pos-db.xml
```

part is something I added later, in an attempt to force Nr 8 and 9 to be FC instead of DT

Thank you in advance

Comment: Oohkay .. Apprently 08 is less than 4 in batch. I removed the 0 from the FOR loop (1,2,3,4 and so forth), and put it down in the viable instead (_POS00%%B). And everything works fine. Solved my own problem :)

Comment: You could post your comment as an answer and even accept it, so the question appears as solved to other users...

Comment: It's not that it's less than 4, it's just that batch considers numbers that start with 0 to be octal, and 08 isn't a valid number in octal.

Comment: Thanks  aschipfl. Pretty new here.

Comment: The three-letters comparisons (`gtr`, `lss`, etc) always try to convert the operands to numbers; if one number start with `0` and include any `8` or `9` and the other number is correct, the comparison is false. The `==` comparison always compare strings. Try: `if 010 equ 8 echo True` or `if 0x10 equ 16 echo True`

Answer (score 0):

SomethingDark gave this explanation.

It's not that it's less than 4, it's just that batch considers numbers that start with 0 to be octal, and 08 isn't a valid number in octal

Thank you :)